# Flex4 Right Click Spark List using ContextMenu()

Tags: apache-flex, list, flex4, contextmenu, right-click

I would like to add custom right clicks to a number of spark list controls.
I have tried the following as an item renderer. (as per the flex 4 cook book).

Full Render code here http://pastebin.com/Kx8tJ1cY

When I right click on the Spark List I simply get the Adobe Default Context menu.
This is the same default behaviour I had before I added any code to this.

Could anyone tell me how to add right clicks to List Items in Flex 4.

Please and Thank you.

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? You can't see the ContextMenu?

Comment: @Florian F the default context menu always shows.
@Jason Towne, I hit accept when I get a valid answer. If I find my own answer then I leave it.

Comment: "This does not work at all" is not enough information for us to help you. What's not working?

Comment: Hi Florian F,

The default contextMenu always stays in play. I'm not sure why.

I should see my added item but I do not. I also call availableFieldMenu.hideBuiltInItems() which has no effect.

Many thanks for any help you can give, I'm stumped. 
Every example I have seen points to the fact that this should work, but yet all I get back is the default context menu.

Full Render code here http://pastebin.com/Kx8tJ1cY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem/solution. You cant use context menus if there are Vboxes or Tab Navigators. Which is insane because it means I cant do relative layout properly or decent variable width design.

Quoted from: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html

For example, if a DataGrid control is a child of a TabNavigator or VBox container, the DataGrid control cannot have its own context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Christopher Huyler posted [something similar](http://www.huyler.net/flexblog/2009/02/02/taking-control-of-right-click-in-adobe-flex/) (source code [available here](http://www.huyler.net/flexblog/projects/FlexRightClick/FlexRightClick.zip)). From the article:

Start out by grabbing the Javascript code from [Google's code repository](http://code.google.com/p/custom-context-menu/).

**Step 1 – Setup custom context menu code**

Create a new Flex project in Flex Builder.  Copy rightclick.js and swfobject.js into the html-template folder of your project.  From here, I had to make several changes…

- I modified the RightClick.init() function to accept an object and container value as input.  This allows me to pass in the name of the application as the object instead of having it be called the same thing every time.
- I included rightclick.js and swfobject.js in the header of index.template.html.
- I added a new div to the body called “flashcontent”.
- I added an onload handler to the body tag to initialize RightClick
- I replaced AC_FL_RunContent(…) with new SWFObject(…) making sure to maintain all template variables.

After making these changes, I verified that no right-click context menu appears in my application.

**Step 2 – Listen for the rightClick event**

Next I added a few lines to the main mxml file of my application to listen for the ExternalInterface event that will be dispatched when I right-click my appliction.

```
private function handleCreationComplete():void
{
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("rightClick", handleRightClick);
}

private function handleRightClick():void
{
    Alert.show("Right Click Success!");
}
```

**Step 3 – Dispatch an event to the correct object**

Getting the event to the main application is easy, but we actually want the appropriate child object to be notified when the right-click event occurs.  Since I am not using any double-click events in my application I decided I would treat every right-click event like a double-click event.  Users without a two button mouse (aka Mac users) can simply double-click to get the same menu while users with a two button mouse just have to right-click.  Here is how I make sure the event is dispatched to the appropriate object.

```
private function handleRightClick():void
{
    var objects:Array = systemManager.getObjectsUnderPoint(
        new Point(mouseX,mouseY));
    if (objects.length>0)
    {
        var object:Object = objects[objects.length-1];
        var relatedObject:InteractiveObject;
        if (object is InteractiveObject)
            relatedObject = object as InteractiveObject;
        else if (object.parent && object.parent is InteractiveObject)
            relatedObject = object.parent;
        var event:MouseEvent = new MouseEvent(
            MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK,true,false,mouseX,mouseY,
            relatedObject);
        object.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Any native way to get right click to work? I really dont want to use JS?

Comment: @Craig Mc, To my knowledge, all solutions to override the native right click functionality involve javascript. If you don't want to use javascript, there's always ContextMenus http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Menus_4.html. This will add menu options to the default Adobe context menu.

Comment: Hi thats the one Im trying to use, ContextMenus are my problem, they dont display. I always get the default context menu.